# Including other Docker files in my Docker file

Tags: dockerfile

I would like to build a custom Docker file. I start with Ubuntu

```
FROM ubuntu
```

But I would also like to add buildpack-deps:stretch

I understand that I am only allowed to use FROM once, so short of copying the contents of buildpack-deps:stretch into my Docker file, how do I add it to my Docker file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, simply "including" another Dockerfile does not work. But, you actually *are allowed* to use multiple `FROM` statements, if you use multistage builds (cf. [the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)).

For example, you could do something like this:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stretch AS build

RUN echo "hello world!" > /tmp/foo

FROM ubuntu

COPY --from=build /tmp/foo .

CMD ["cat", "foo"]
```

Running `docker build --tag foo . && docker run --rm foo` results in `hello world!`. You could replace the first `RUN` statement with the compilation of something or whatever you are planning to do.

There are more ways for using multistage builds, e.g. using `FROM build` in our example directly.